# PHP get query string from a string

Tags: php

I have a string with a URL

```
$string = "http://www.yahoo.com/foo.php?bar=201";
```

all i want is the query string without everything else.

obviously cant user query_string, help appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax, sense makes none.

Answer (score 5):

```
$parts = parse_url($string);
echo $parts['query'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php